# COUNT reducing results?

Tags: mysql

A query without `COUNT` returns 3 records, with only 1.

```
SELECT  `blog_cate` . * , COUNT( blogi.blog_cate ) AS num
FROM (
`blog_cate`
)
JOIN  `blogi` ON  `blogi`.`blog_cate` =  `blog_cate`.`blogi_cate_url`
```

results:

```
+----+------------------+----------------+-----+
| id | blogi_cate_title | blogi_cate_url | num |
+----+------------------+----------------+-----+
|  1 | Базы данных      | batabase       |   3 |
+----+------------------+----------------+-----+
```

And the same query, but without a `COUNT`:

```
SELECT  `blog_cate` . * 
FROM (
`blog_cate`
)
JOIN  `blogi` ON  `blogi`.`blog_cate` =  `blog_cate`.`blogi_cate_url`
```

That returns me 3 records:

```
+----+------------------+----------------+
| id | blogi_cate_title | blogi_cate_url |
+----+------------------+----------------+
|  1 | Базы данных      | batabase       |
|  1 | Базы данных      | batabase       |
|  3 | Разработка       | razrabotka     |
+----+------------------+----------------+
```

Is it possible to use a `COUNT` and have a normal results?

p.s. tables:

```
+----+------------+
| id | blog_cate  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | batabase   |
|  2 | batabase   |
|  3 | razrabotka |
+----+------------+

+----+------------------+----------------+
| id | blogi_cate_title | blogi_cate_url |
+----+------------------+----------------+
|  1 | Базы данных      | batabase       |
|  2 | PHP              | php            |
|  3 | Разработка       | razrabotka     |
+----+------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COUNT() with out a group by will group all records and produce a count of them.  Adding more fields to the select will only show the details of the first record

Comment: So I need just to add a group by?

Comment: I'm not sure what 'normal' results mean from your question.  Please create an example result set you want at the end of the query and from that someone can show what the best group by needed is

Comment: I think ok in first query with `GROUP BY`: SELECT  `blog_cate` . * , COUNT( blogi.blog_cate ) AS num
FROM (
`blog_cate`
)
JOIN  `blogi` ON  `blogi`.`blog_cate` =  `blog_cate`.`blogi_cate_url` GROUP BY (blogi.blog_cate)

Answer (score 1):

You could build one query to get the three rows and one query to get the count result and join them via cross join to combine every detail row with the count row.